# Popover image gallery not working in iPad iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, popover

Recently my app has rejected from App Review because I wasn't using Popover. 
then I changed my coding into following. but still I'm not getting popup window in simulator.

Always getting normal iPhone photo choosing method and it makes app crash.

Also its not even printing "working".

```
 @IBAction func chooseGallery(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

  //imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
  //presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)//4
  //imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        println("Working")// to test this part

        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)//4
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = (sender)

        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
     }     
}
```

Comment: I found the answer. i wasnt using `universal` in target devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine for me with some modifications, In the following example I going to present a Popover only for iPad just like you.

```
@IBAction func showNextViewController(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController") as! NexViewController

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {            
        nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        presentViewController(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let popover = nextViewController.popoverPresentationController {             
            popover.barButtonItem = sender
            popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up

            // to set it size
            nextViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,500)
        }
    }    
}
```

Because I don't know the class of `UIViewController` you're trying to present I just made one myself without nothing inside, and I instantiate it in the `@IBAction` to avoid keep references to it (is just for test purposes).

Just some observations:

- When you're going to present popovers you need to set only one of the two follwoing:

  - `barButtonItem`
  - `sourceView`, `sourceRect`

In the above example just like you set the `barButtonItem` you don't need anything more.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

picker.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext